# is it possible for a line L to intersect with all three sides of triangle ABC?

Tags: geometry, logic, euclidean-geometry

say the line bisects the triangle ABC, my thinking is if it intersects at point A, then it intersect side AB and AC, since point A is a point on those two sides. then the line would continue and intersect side BC, thus intersecting all three sides

is this correct?

Comment: It really depends on how you define the *sides* of a triangle...

Comment: The sides being segments AB, BC and AC with A, B, and C being vertices. ...unless you mean something else?

Comment: Well, some authors define the *side* as an "open" segment, i.e. $A$ does neither belong to the side $AB$ nor to the side $CA$. If you are using the other definition, your reasoning seems right to me

Comment: i've never heard of open segments before and the book i'm using doesn't mention it so i'm assuming they're closed thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Welcome to MSE!

You're exactly right. If you say that a line going through $A$ intersects $\overline{AB}$ and $\overline{AC}$, then your argument shows that you can build a line intersecting all three sides:

Just take the line through $A$ and any point on $\overline{BC}$.

However, this should feel somewhat like cheating, and you might wonder if you can find a line which intersects all three sides of a triangle *in the middle* of the edges (rather than by cleverly double counting the vertex).

With some experimentation, you'll probably convince yourself that this is impossible, and indeed it is. There's a theorem that says

> If a line passes thorugh a [convex](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convex_set) region in the plane, it intersects the boundary of that region in exactly two points.

Since triangles are convex, this means a line can only touch the sides of the triangle in two points. Thankfully, with your definition, this is ok since the point $A$ can count towards two of the three edges! But it means that there's no way for a line to intersect the *middle* of all three sides.

---

I hope this helps ^_^